# How to make the cursor shape dependent on the current Vim mode using iTerm2 on OS X and zsh

Tags: vim, zsh, iterm

I am using zsh and iTerm2 to edit with Vim. I really love the integration and portability, and because of that I have chosen not to use MacVim. But....

I can't work out how to get my cursor to change from a block to a line when in Vim's insert mode. I've been lead to believe that it's not possible by standard means, but people seem to think that it is possible using zsh. I've done as much Google searching as I can take without an answer, any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=710&q=cursor